# Why does my Thunkable calculator app keep returning NaN when operators like (+,=,-,×,÷) are used?

Tags: calculator, nan, thunkable

Why does my Thunkable calculator app keep saying NaN every time I type in an operator like(+,=,-etc)

I tried checking codes from my teacher but it still didn't work (BTW if you are wondering why I didn't ask her It's because It's 3:45 AM in India)I expected it to be like any normal calculator and the results were unexpected any time I type in an operator like(+,=,-,×,÷)It would type back with NaN

Comment: Post the (relevant) code here, otherwise it's impossible to know what's going on.